# how to edit left column when left.phtml is missing in magento?

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to display the sub-categories from a certain category in magento  in the left side bar. I found a few solutions saying I have to change the code in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\navigation\left.phtm but I only have top.phtml and verticalcollapse.phtml. However the code that displays the left column is this getChildHtml('left') ?>. This is in app/design/frontend/default/forest_classyshop/template/page/2collumn-left.phtml.

My question is where can I find the code "left" that should be in the left.phtml that's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's probably located at app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\navigation\left.phtml.

Magento will look in Your Template for a file. if not there it will then look in Default for that file. If not there it will look at Base. Sounds like someone has deleted that file in Base.. I would look in app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_TEMPLATE\template\catalog\navigation\left.phtml
Then
app\design\frontend\Default\Default\template\catalog\navigation\left.phtml

Comment: thanks for the tips! it was in app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\navigation\verticalcollapse.phtml! In case someone has the same problem

Comment: verticalcollapse‌​.phtml must be a mod.. I have never seen that file. :)